# How can I change the GRUB splash image in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, grub2, permissions, plymouth, png

NOTE: I am not after themes... more just hacking what's here as its faster.

In Ubuntu 18.04 I am trying to change the `grub.png/splash.png` image, the one you see when GRUB asks you what system you want to boot up, Linux/Windows/etc.

I know how to give myself permissions over a whole folder and its files in `usr/share/background/` (which is how I changed my login screen), but if I am going any place near GRUB I want to only give permissions to the actual image - not to GRUB or kernel or other files inside.

Ideas?

Comment: [Here's](http://brej.org/blog/?p=158) what I used to learn Plymouth. Not too in depth at the start but should help if you invest some reading time.

Comment: Hmmm there is no ect/default/grub in my system... (I'm using ubutnu18.04 as the base distro)

Comment: Use @WinEunuuchs2Unix when replying to me otherwise I'll never see your comment. I stumbled across this by accident. Use `cat /etc/default/grub` to see the file contents. There was a spelling mistake in your directory name. The easiest way is to copy the text from this comment and paste it in your terminal.

Comment: With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that are posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed, so it's possible they'll already be gone by the time you check back in here. In that case, you'll just be thoroughly confused on what I'm talking about ;-).

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial on grub splash screen images is [Here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/grub-splash-image/)

b)  sudo has to come first before your chmod command

c)  David answered your question on plymouth in the comments area

- Cheers

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04, not debian - as such the places it tells me to look for to tweak the grub are not in this system.